# My log in function just reload my current page and not log me in? Laravel 7 conflict with closure?

Tags: php, laravel-7

I can't seems to get my login to work, I keep the same input code using **form** after i click login it just reload the page! oddly enough when I revert back to the original code it keeps the same error until I changes the host with **php artisan serve** , Is it a cache problem because i got **Closure** Package installed which won't allow me to **php route:cache**.

EDIT: in the original code the link wasn't displayed on the URL bar, but in the new code it displayed as follow `http://127.0.0.1:8888/login?_token=NKzj3rreuUJU9IsatQHek6t1pq8wVBIg4ZLIKRtC&email=admin%40example.net&password=secret`

For reference:

My original Laravel **login.blade.php** code, and it works.

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Route::has('password.request'))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then i change it to this, which doesn't work.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/Linearicons-Free-v1.0.0/icon-font.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animate/animate.css">   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/css-hamburgers/hamburgers.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/animsition/css/animsition.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/select2/select2.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/util.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

   <div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-login100">
        <div class="wrap-login100">
            <form class="login100-form validate-form">

                <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34">
                    Account Login
                </span>
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                    @csrf
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus>

                    @error('email')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>
        
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password">

                    @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @enderror
                </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                            <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-group container-login100-form-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="login100-form-btn">
                        {{ __('Login') }}
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="w-full text-center p-t-27 p-b-239">
                    <span class="txt1">
                        Forgot
                    </span>

                    <a href="#" class="txt2">
                        User name / password?
                    </a>
                </div>
            </form>

        <div class="login100-more" style="background-image: url('images/bg-01.jpg');"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you modify the login controller ? Please add some of it if yes.

Comment: I haven't touch the Login Controller, it still the same as the original Laravel ui/auth.

Comment: It seems like I have extra `form` tag, `<form class="login100-form validate-form">` try to remove it

Comment: Holy, i didn't notice that at all!!! thank you!!!

changed `<form class="login100-form validate-form">`
to `<form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">` and deleted the `<form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">.`

Comment: glad to hear that, i'll add an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have an extra `form` tag :

```
         <form class="login100-form validate-form"> //Here it is

            <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34">
                Account Login
            </span>
            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                @csrf
```